# Minimum distance of a code

Tags: coding-theory

Is there a way to compute minimum distance of a code given a systematic parity check matrix? I know that min dist is smallest number $d$ such that there exists $d$ linearly dependant columns. I am looking in particular to find minimum distance of binary (codes over $\mathbb{F}_{2^l}$) quasi-cyclic  of rate q/q+1. Parity check matrix for such codes have a structure
$H=[I|C_1|C_2|...|C_m]$ where each $C_¡$ is a from class of circulant matrices. It may be useful that one can treat these codes as modules.
Or even if there are any approximate algoruihms for this ?

Comment: Since you can take any code, and find a systematic parity check matrix for an equivalent code, the complexity class of this problem doesn't depend on whether there's a systematic parity check matrix or not.

Answer (score 7):

The problem for an arbitrary binary code is NP-hard.

[Reference:](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=641542) Alexander Vardy, “The Intractability of Computing
the Minimum Distance of a Code,” *IEEE Trans. Inf. Thy.,* **Vol. 43** pp. 1757--1766.

Comment: Shot anything in particular for QC codes or may be an approximate algorithm for finding minimum distance. What I am looking for is a way to construct QC codes with high minimum distance. So even algorithms giving lower bounds (non-trivial) are worth a try.

Answer (score 2):

I hate to reopen an old topic but I just want to add for future searches that there is no way to do this in general unless you can logic-out the weight enumerators, but for a specific instance of a code in the family the Brouwer-Zimmermann algorithm gives you what you want. This is built-in to many coding theory programming libraries.